# Regarding checking if Map contains a certain key

Tags: java, collections

I have an value patient id which is I am getting from backend in my application as shown below

```
 String PatientId = rxDetails.getPatient().getPatientID() ; //patient ID recieved from backend
```

Here is another Map which store the details as shown below

```
 Map <String ,List<String>> m = new LinkedHashMap LinkedHashMap<String,List<String>>();
  List<String> info = new ArrayList<String>();
                info.add("ScriptInfo");
                info.add("Name");
                info.add("PhoneNo");
  m.put(PatientID ,info);
  transaction.setValue(ITransaction.PATIENT_DETAILS_FOR_CCV, ppvdetails);//please ignore this line as it is my framework dependent and in this line I am storing the Map
```

As shown it also stores the patientId

Now my query is that I have to cross check at certian condition that the patient id that is I am getting from the backend the very first one is allready
present in Map m or not

Now as shown Below I am taking the reference of Map m in another Map named ValidatedPatientList

```
Map ValidatedPatientList = (LinkedHashMap)transaction.getValue(ITransaction.VALIDATED_CCV_PH_NBR);//please ignore this line as it is my framework dependent and in this line I am retreving the Mao
if(ValidatedPatientList != null && !ValidatedPatientList.isEmpty())
      {
       Iterator iterator = ValidatedPatientList.keySet().iterator();
          if(iterator.hasNext())
          {
```

As shown above Now I have to extract all the keys of ValidatedPatientList first and then have to compare that it contains the very first patient id or not, please
advise how to achieve this..!!

Comment: Add this link to your bookmarks, and check the documentation each time you wonder how a class must be used and what methods it offers: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/

Comment: `if (validatedPatientList.containsKey(patientId)) {}`

Answer (score 1):

Use `HashMap#containsKey` . It will return true if the map contains a mapping for the specified key.

Javadoc for `java.util.HashMap`

```
/**
 * Returns <tt>true</tt> if this map contains a mapping for the
 * specified key.
 *
 * @param   key   The key whose presence in this map is to be tested
 * @return <tt>true</tt> if this map contains a mapping for the specified
 * key.
 */
public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
    return getEntry(key) != null;
}
```

Code sample :

```
Map<String ,List<String ValidatedPatientList = (LinkedHashMap<String ,List<String)transaction.getValue(ITransaction.VALIDATED_CCV_PH_NBR);
if(ValidatedPatientList != null && !ValidatedPatientList.isEmpty())
{  
   if (validatedPatientList.containsKey(patientId)) //returns true if map contains the key
   {...}
}
```

Comment: List<String> list = validatedPatientList.get(patientId);if(list!=null){//do something}

Comment: These are more or less the same except for you have to explicitly check for the existence of a key i.e. whether `list` is null or not but containsKey() returns a boolean which is the requirement in this case.

Comment: @rahul Thanks a lot , I have followed this approach   if (ValidatedPatientList != null && !ValidatedPatientList.isEmpty() && (validatedPatientList.containsKey(patientId)) )
        {

Comment: @rahulroc I think this will also more or same and it will also work

Comment: Yes... This is exactly the same. I just put that under separate if statement for your better understanding